# XLS se crea solo con las cabeceras, sin los detalles ingresados por el usuario

Tags: php, html

Tengo este código php que supuestamente me crea un xls con los datos que introduce el usuario junto a sus cabeceras, pero solo me muestra la cabecera y no los datos introducidos por el usuario,
tal que me muestra la cabecera de Apellido, Nombre y debajo de estas mismas debería mostrarme el apellido que ha introducido el usuario en la página web, pero esos datos no los incluye en el xls y no sé por qué.

Aquí está el [código](https://codepaste.xyz/posts/OKdSUgsllPh4IL83pvRW):

```
<?php 
    $success = "../html/pass.html";
    $error = "";
    
    
    $lbChar = " ";  
    
    if($_POST){
        $array = $_POST;
    } else if($_GET){           
        $array = $_GET;
    } else {
            die("You must Access this file through a form.");   
    }   

    if(!$array['filename']){
        
        $array['filename'] = "form.xls";    
    
    } else {
        if(!(stristr($array['filename'],".xls"))){
            $array['filename'] = $array['filename'] . ".xls";
        }
    }

    
    $tab = "\t";    //chr(9);
    $cr = "\n";     //chr(13);
    
    if($array){
            
            $keys = array_keys($array);
            foreach($keys as $key){
                if(strtolower($key) != 'filename' && strtolower($key) != 'title'){ 
                    $header .= $key . $tab;
                }
            }
            $header .= $cr;
            
            
            foreach($keys as $key){
                if(strtolower($key) != 'filename' && strtolower($key) != 'title'){ 

                    $array[$key] = str_replace("\n",$lbChar,$array[$key]);
                    $array[$key] = preg_replace('/([\r\n])/e',"ord('$1')==10?'':''",$array[$key]);
                    $array[$key] = str_replace("\\","",$array[$key]);
                    $array[$key] = str_replace($tab, "    ", $array[$key]);
                    $data .= $array[$key] . $tab ;
                }
            }
            $data .= $cr;
            
            if (file_exists($array['filename'])) {
                $final_data = $data;        
            } else {
                $final_data = $header . $data;      
            }
            
            $fp = fopen($array['filename'],"a"); 
            $array['filename']
            
            if($fp){
                
                fwrite($fp,$final_data);
                fclose($fp);
                
                header("Location: $success");
                
            } else {
                
                header("Location: $error");
            }
    }
    
?>
```

Comment: El codigo debe estar insertado en la pregunta, para eso estan las herramientas cuando creas la pregunta, puede pasar que los enlaces que dejaste mueran y alli la pregunta perderia todo sentido, lee [ask].

Comment: Por favor, lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score 0):

Es muy importante tener habilitados todos los errores de PHP (incluidos `notice`y `warning`) en entornos de desarrollo porque, en ocasiones como estas, los `warning` permiten seguir ejecutando el código pero generan un error.

En este caso, aparecen varios `notice` y `warning` y uno de ellos es el que está provocando que los datos no se incluyan:

```
$array[$key] = preg_replace('/([\r\n])/e',"ord('$1')==10?'':''",$array[$key]);
```

El warning anuncia lo siguiente: *preg_replace(): The /e modifier is no longer supported, use preg_replace_callback instead*. Si comentas la línea, verás que funciona. Tienes una buena explicación aquí: https://cybmeta.com/php-the-e-modifier-is-no-longer-supported

Esa línea es un poco extraña por el segundo parámetro, donde estás comparando un valor con 10 para, independientemente de dicha comparación, devolver un valor vacío.

En lugar de reemplazar tantos textos mediante `str_replace()` o `preg_replace()`, yo trataría de utilizar *filter_var()*: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php

Otros `notice` y `warning` que aparecen son los siguientes:

> Notice: Undefined index: filename
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: header
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: data

Ahora, en cuanto a tu código, al margen de la corrección de la línea del que falla, te recomendaría varios cambios (la solución al `preg_replace()` se basa en lo que devuelve la comparación que estás haciendo):

```
<?php

$success = "../html/pass.html";
$error   = "";
$lbChar  = " "; 

// ¿Se pueden enviar los valores a través de POST y de GET? Revisaría esta parte del código
if ($_POST) {
    $array = $_POST;
} elseif ($_GET) {
    $array = $_GET;
} else {
    die("You must Access this file through a form.");   
}

// Modificaciones 1 y 2: la validación del índice 'filename' no funciona, usa empty() para comprobar que existe y no está vacío (1) y no hace falta anidar un único if dentro del else, utiliza mejor un elseif (y 2)
if (empty($array['filename'])) {
    $array['filename'] = "form.xls";    
} elseif ( ! stristr($array['filename'], ".xls")) {
    $array['filename'] = $array['filename'] . ".xls";
}

$tab = "\t"; //chr(9);
$cr  = "\n"; //chr(13);

// Modificación 3 - prescinde de la condición `if ($array)`, ya que siempre va a existir, bien con los valores de $_POST o los de $_GET (de no existir lanzaría el die())

// Modificación 4 - define $header y $data con dos strings vacíos para evitar los errores notice que se generan cuando tratas de añadir texto a dos variables que no se han definido previamente
$header = "";
$data   = "";

// Modificación 5 - evita hacer dos iteraciones sobre el array $key, ya que puedes añadir el contenido a $header y $data en el mismo bucle
$keys = array_keys($array);

foreach ($keys as $key) {
    if (strtolower($key) !== 'filename' && strtolower($key) !== 'title') { 
        $header .= $key . $tab;

        $array[$key] = str_replace("\n", $lbChar, $array[$key]);
        // Modificación 6 - Corregir la línea que provoca el fallo en base a lo que interpreto necesitas
        $array[$key] = preg_replace('/([\r\n])/', "", $array[$key]);
        $array[$key] = str_replace("\\","", $array[$key]);
        $array[$key] = str_replace($tab, "    ", $array[$key]);
        
        $data .= $array[$key] . $tab ;
    }
}

$header .= $cr;
$data   .= $cr;

if (file_exists($array['filename'])) {
    $final_data = $data;        
} else {
    $final_data = $header . $data;      
}

$fp = fopen($array['filename'], "a"); 

// Modificación 7 - elimina la línea que sólo pone $array['filename'];
if ($fp){
    fwrite($fp,$final_data);
    fclose($fp);
    header("Location: $success");
    // Modificación 8 - añadir die() o exit() justo después de usar header("Location...") para asegurarse de interrumpir la ejecución y garantizar que la redirección se hace correctamente
    die();
}

// Modificación 9 - prescindir del else final e incluir su código fuera de él, ya que o se guarda correctamente, lo que provoca la redirección e interrupción del código, o se continua ejecutando
header("Location: $error");
die();
```